# Zend Framework 1 to Zend Framework 2 use of models

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm really new to Zend Framework 2, but i love some features that it comes along with it. I've started an app in order to learn faster after reading the documentation on [zend page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/) , not properly diggested I must say.

Afterwards i install this marvelous peace on a [blog](http://ctrl-f5.net/php/zf2-skeleton-application-with-doctrine-and-ctrllib/), it has a functional skeleton with some usefull modules.

So after i got it running and finished designing my own database I struggled to find a way to use my new tables. I was used in zf1 to generate 4 folders of models table base, table, row base and row. How do I do it here ? what would be the best practice in using some of the same coding standards ?

I know that i could use doctrine 2 entities that comes with zf2 in a different module ?
I also tryied a model generator module, but it did not work from the first time and i was not really sure that was the path i needed.

Comment: Use of models is perfectly explained within the QuickStart of [the documentation right here](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/database-and-models.html)

Comment: Thanks @Sam for the link, I haven't explored those docs yet, althought I discovered some of the same I still haven't figuered out a way to autogenerate the needed models to use with my app, nor where is the best place to put them in the folder structure or how to use the table gateway with doctrine entities

Comment: Doctrine stands against TableGateway. Doctrine is an ORM. See [DoctrineModule\Docs](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md) for some information. Folderstructure is always identical to the namespace.

Comment: Thanks for your link @Sam, i have one more question thought, i know that zf2 revolves around namespaces, but i don't get this namespace persona, do i need to define my project's namespace somewhere ? i get constant errors from routing from example, that i have not defined the __NAMESPACE__ : ` Undefined index: __NAMESPACE__ in /Event/DispatchListener.php ` in a line of code: $moduleResource = implode('.', array(
            \Ctrl\Permissions\Resources::SET_ROUTES,
            $routeParams['__NAMESPACE__'],
        ));

Comment: Impossible to answer without your routing configuration. But since this error comes from the `Ctrl`-Namespace, this is a support thing for that blog you've mentioned. Most likely that Module wants the route config ala `__NAMESPACE__ => Ctrl, controller => Foo` or so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of models is perfectly explained within the QuickStart of the [documentation right here](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/database-and-models.html). as suggested by @[Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/958642/sam)